# Access class name from mixin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixins

In my Rails project, I store global settings in a string-indexed hash where each class (model) has a "namespace" for its own settings. For example, the News model might have the settings 'news.stories_per_page' or 'news.show_date'.

To avoid having to name-mangle everywhere, I have a mixin which provides general class methods for accessing these settings. Using this mixin, I could access 'news.show_date' with code like:

```
News.setting :show_date
=> true
```

Now, here's the problem. In order to generate the string 'news.show_date', I need to know the class name of the model that mixes my module in. But within a class method,

```
self.class
=> Class
```

which is not very helpful to me. In my naïve implemetation, this caused all models to store their settings under the 'class.' namespace, which is unacceptable.

I apologise for not being able to state the problem more clearly. I'm somewhat new to Ruby and have not understood its object model fully. The problem may have something to do with the [kludge which seems to be required in Ruby to mix in class methods](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/#88311).

Comment: There are so many ways to do this (most of which differ for me from what you have). What are your hard-and-fast requirements? Must you have a single hash with that uses strings?

Comment: @Phrogz: The hard-and-fast req. is to be able to serialise ruby objects into a database which can be accessed on a per-class (per-model) basis. I'm using the gem "rails-settings-cached" for that, but there are probably many ways. I asked this question mostly because I wanted to understand the logic behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of a class is the `name` of a class:

```
module Foo
  def whoami
    self.name
  end
end

class Bar
  extend Foo
end

p Bar.whoami #=> "Bar"
```

I would not create some string; I would either create a new hash of settings per class:

```
module Settings
  def setting(name,value=:GIT_DA_VALUE)
    @_class_settings ||= {}  # Create a new hash on this object, if needed
    if value==:GIT_DA_VALUE
      @_class_settings[name]
    else
      @_class_settings[name] = value
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  extend Settings
end
class Bar
  extend Settings
end
Foo.setting(:a,42)

p Foo.setting(:a), #=> 42
  Foo.setting(:b), #=> nil
  Bar.setting(:a)  #=> nil  (showing that settings are per class)
```

...or else I would index a single global hash (if required) by the class object itself:

```
module Settings
  # A single two-level hash for all settings, indexed by the object
  # upon which the settings are applied; automatically creates
  # a new settings hash for each object when a new object is peeked at
  SETTINGS = Hash.new{ |h,obj| h[obj]={} }
  def setting(name,value=:GIT_DA_VALUE)
    if value==:GIT_DA_VALUE
      SETTINGS[self][name]
    else
      SETTINGS[self][name] = value
    end
  end
end

# Usage is the same as the above; settings are unique per class
```

Comment: +1 Your answer is easier then mine. Perhaps a problem: `#name` returns a String, not the class.

Comment: @Phrogz: Would you say that self.name called from a class method is the equivalent of self.class.to_s called from an instance method?

Comment: @jforberg Since `self.class` in an instance _is_ the `self` of a class, your question is really _"is [`to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-to_s) the same as [`name`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-name) for a class?"_ As you can see from the descriptions, source code, and experimentation, the answer is _"Usually, yes, but not always."_

Answer (score 2):

Instead using `self.class` you may use `self.ancestors` or more detailed `self.ancestors.first`:

```
module Mixin
  def setting(name)
    puts "call #{self.ancestors.first}.#{__method__} with #{name}"
  end
end

class A
  extend Mixin
end

A.setting :a  #-> call A.setting with a
```

Comment: Use `extend Mixin` instead of going through the singleton class.

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks - I adapted my answer. I was sure there is an easier way, but I didn't find it ad hoc.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to instantiate `self` within each of the class methods and call `class` on the instance. It's not a particularly beautiful solution, but it seems to work.

```
module SettingsMixin
  def self.included receiver
     receiver.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def setting(key)
      class_name = self.new.class # => ClassThatMixesMeIn

      # Setting-fetching logic here...

    end
  end
end
```

The code within `ClassMethods` is not parsed (or so it seems) until it is called from `ClassThatMixesMeIn`. It will then have the correct value.

Comment: `self.new.class` is the same as `self`.